# XML to CSV from serial input

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi3, cheminformatics

I use a Raspberry 3, with a CO² analyser connected with some USB/RS232 converter.

Raw data come smoothly on /dev/ttyUSB0, and that data need to be logged to .csv (at this point of my work not so much then, i must admit).

The only stuff, about conversion, that i found were from xml FILES to csv, not from some continuous data stream.

Will i have to put that stream to an xml file before parsing and write to the .csv ?

[here my "code"](http://pastebin.com/36JkhRJJ). I was able to see that my issue is coming from line 63 (therefore, on the buffer parsing).

Thanks to the brave ones who'll help me make this work instead of taking the easy way i was talking about hahah (copy to xml file before converting) !

Comment: Hello everyone, btw (sorry for the rudeness)

Comment: You will have to have parsable xml to be able to parse it - a complete fragment with opening tag `<li820...>` and matching closing tag `</li820>`. Unless you can ensure that then of course et.parse will fail every time. You could put try/except around the et.parse and get some more data/try to parse until there isn't an exception - but if data comes in which includes just the leading < of the next frame, the parse will never succeed. I think you will have to at least read data from a < into a buffer until you get a > and only then try to parse it,

Comment: You may have to further refine that by only parsing when you see `</li820>` at the end of the buffer. What a truly horrible idea, using XML as a serial protocol data format. Effectively what you will have to do is get an in-memory copy of a complete XML fragment and parse it. You'll never succeed if you try to incrementally parse XML.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

As for my sensor's output..indeed it sucks to do so with xml (and afterward i'll need to add an other device from the same company..). Besides, even to config/control it the communication works the same way.

When writing the raw data in a txt file, lines 78&80, it extract/write itself rows from <li820> to </li820> on every fp.write (thanks to the use of buff.readline i suppose) so 2steps-work might be "the way".

Thanks again ! Nice day